# Datasheet for a SM430803K?

Tags: led

I have 4 or 5 of [these](http://www.aitendo.com/product/2857). Any way to tell what pin is the cathode?

Comment: You should have tried translating the page before posting this.

Comment: I did, guess I missed it. thanks for the direct link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a common anode 16 segment LED display. 12 and 17 are the common pins (anode). The figure gives the details.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A 9v battery and a 1k series resistor used as a tester makes it easy to identify each segment and which pin is common to all.  The polarity used to get the segments to light will verify if the cathode is common.